# Typesetting these three keyboard characters: ' ´ `

Tags: symbols

How can I typeset keyboard characters as they appear in a normal text file? I want to typeset the following three characters within parentheses ('´`) so that they appear exactly as in the text file (or on the screen). I have tried the verbatim environment, but that did not work. The character ['] was typeset as a single closing apostrophe, [´] was not typeset at all, while [`] was typeset as a single opening apostrophe.

I use TexStudio and TeXLive on Windows, and have it set for UTF-8 encoding.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
' ´  ` 
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: some common keyboards (the ones usually used in the u.s., for example) don't have all three.  on the u.s. "qwerty" keyboard, only the "backtick" (= grave) and the apostrophe have their own keys.  this was the model on which tex was developed, so some conventions had to be adopted.  use of the apostrophe also for the single right quote (and, by extension, for the acute) is "normal" to a person who learned to type using that keyboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\textquotesingle
\textasciiacute
\textasciigrave

\verb+'´`+
\end{document}
```